# Create link url in zf2 controller

Tags: zend-framework2

I am a starter in zend-framework 2.
If i need to create a link in `view.phtml`, using this:

```
$this->url('router',array())
```

Now i need to create a link in controller and save to database.
Any Idea?

Comment: Use the `url()` controller plugin -> http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#zend-mvc-controller-plugins-url

Answer (score 15, accepted):

try this:

```
public function someAction()
{
    //codes

    //use url plugin in controller
    $link = $this->url()->fromRoute('router', array());
    //or use ViewHelperManager in controller or other place that you have ServiceManager
    $link = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('url')->__invoke('router',array());

    //codes
}
```

Comment: A lot better way is to use $this->url() plugin, you don`t have to pull it from ViewHelperManager.

Comment: yes, but this is a general way to create url, in controller or in onBootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

invoke viewhelper:

```
public function algoAction()
{
    $url = $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('viewhelpermanager')
            ->get('url');
    $link = $url('router',array());
}
```

zf v2.4

also

```
$this->url()->fromRoute('home',[],['force_canonical' => true]);
```

['force_canonical' => true] *is optional

Answer (score -1):

Use url() controller plugin:

```
public function fooAction(){

    //other code

    $this->url('routename');

    //other stuff
}
```

Comment: Wrong. From a controller, you must use `$this->url()->fromRoute(...)` and not `$this->url(...)`. See other answers.